# how to execute originate command from java application

Tags: java

I want to execute originate command from java application.
In free switch bin type following command

```
./fs_cli -X "originate loopback/1235/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)"
```

Its working, now I have to execute this command by running a java app. please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Runtime.exec()`

```
String command = "./fs_cli -X \"originate loopback/1235/default &bridge(sofia/internal/1789)\"";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am getting following errors when running the above program            Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./fs_cli": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:450)
 at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:347)
 at org.freeswitch.esl.client.outbound.example.Call.<init>(Call.java:12)
 at org.freeswitch.esl.client.outbound.example.Call.main(Call.java:15)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2,

Comment: add `bash` to the beginning of the command. If it didn't work, try adding `sh`.